# How do I treat a String as a File in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

In Python it is possible to write

```py
from io import StringIO

with StringIO("some text...") as stream:
    for line in stream:
        # work with the data
        process_line(line)
```

Is there a way I can do the same thing, treat some string as a file object, and apply `Read` trait to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`std::io::Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html):

```rust
use std::io::{Read, Cursor};

fn use_read_trait(s: String, buff: &mut [u8]) -> usize {
    let mut c = Cursor::new(s);
    c.read(buff).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: Technically you don't even need `Cursor` if you just want to `Read`, [`Read` is implemented for `&[u8]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-for-%26%5Bu8%5D). Cursor is useful because it also provides seeking.